# I am not able to access HttpUtility.UrlDecode inside my controller

Tags: c#

I am trying to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode method but could not able to do so though I am using System.Web

Comment: Welcome to [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)
! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says: To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the WebUtility class.

WebUtility class is included in `System.Net` namespace